# Display data with a yes or no condition ACF

Tags: php

There is a condition that is fulfilled via ACF yes or no and if it is fulfilled (yes) then I need to display part of my code, if (no) then don't need to display anything

```php
$output .= $value = get_field( "models-ad_fly" );
```

if (yes) then it should be shown - `<div class="icon_plane"><i class="icon-social_fly"></i></div>`

Comment: are you asking how to write an if statement for the contents of `$value`? Your question isn't super clear, I'm assuming there is a checkbox field named `models-ad_fly` and you want to do an `if` statement to check its value? Note that questions about ACF are offtopic here but I suspect this is actually a beginner PHP question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( get_field( "models-ad_fly" ) ):
   echo '<div class="icon_plane"><i class="icon-social_fly"></i></div>';
endif;
```

or if you want to assign the output to a variable

```
if ( get_field( "models-ad_fly" ) ):
   $output .= '<div class="icon_plane"><i class="icon-social_fly"></i></div>';
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I managed to figure it out myself

```
    $value = get_field('model_status');
    if ($value == 'Model on contract (fly)') 
    $output .= '<div class="icon-social_fly"></div>';
```